# frameでできたページを特定のID属性を指定して開くことはできるでしょうか。

Tags: html

法令データ提供システム(http://law.e-gov.go.jp)のページに注釈をつけるウェブページを作りたいと考えています。

frameで2分割して、一方を法令データ提供システム、もう一方を自分で作った注釈のhtmlを開きたいと思っています。そして、特定のコンテンツIDを含むリンクで、そのコンテンツに飛べるようにしたいと思っているのですが、frameでできたページを特定のIDでロードすることは可能でしょうか。

文書で説明するとわかりにくいと思いますが、たとえば法令データ提供システムの日本国憲法のページ(http://law.e-gov.go.jp/cgi-bin/idxselect.cgi?IDX_OPT=4&H_NAME=&H_NAME_YOMI=%82%A0&H_NO_GENGO=H&H_NO_YEAR=&H_NO_TYPE=2&H_NO_NO=&H_FILE_NAME=S21KE000&H_RYAKU=1&H_CTG=1&H_YOMI_GUN=1&H_CTG_GUN=1)で、9条をロードするように指定したリンクを作成することは可能かどうかという意味です。

法律を勉強しているのですが、暗記アプリ(Anki(ankisrs.net))からブラウザを開くリンクが作れるので、法令データ提供システムの特定条文と関連するメモにリンクが貼れれば便利かなと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

### 追記

target属性は理解しているのですが、frameで構成されたウェブサイトへのtarget属性を使ったリンクを作成したいという意味です。

下記のようにframeのsrcにハードコードすれば、そういったサイトは作れるのでしょうが、リンクを作成するために特別なframeのページをtargetごとに無数に作成しなければならなくなってしまいます。

```
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
<frame src="frame_a.htm#1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900000000000000000000000000000">
<frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

やはり、動的なCGIなどが必要でしょうか？

Comment: 役に立つかはわかりませんが、 http://law.e-gov.go.jp/htmldata/S21/S21KE000.html#1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900000000000000000000000000000 このURLを開けば、九条へのリンクになるようです。

Comment: frameページは１つでいいと思いますけど。

Answer (score 1):

リンクから特定のフレームにリンク先を表示するにはtarget属性で指定します。
例えば九条の部分には

```
<a name="1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900000000000000000000000000000">第九条</a>
```

のようにアンカーがあります。
`href`にアンカーを含めたアドレスを指定してtargetにフレーム名を指定します。
例として九条のリンクは次のようになっています。

```
<a href="/htmldata/S21/S21KE000.html#1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900000000000000000000000000000" target="data">第九条</a>
```